# What action or filter can I use to change all the html returned from server for a page?

Tags: plugins, filters, actions, front-end

My plugin will show what the website will look like on a mobile device. This means I need to render a page within an iframe (to display what the website will look like on a mobile device). So if someone goes to http://mywebsite.com/page-slug?mypluginname then the plugin will run and wrap the whole page in an iframe.

Is there an action or a filter my plugin can react to? Ie, on this event I want to wrap the entire page content in an iframe? So something like...

```
function onPageLoad($wholeDocumentContent) {

   return '<html><head></head><body> <iframe width="50%" srcdoc="' . $wholeDocumentContent . '"></iframe> </body></html>;

 }
```

Comment: [This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772510/wordpress-filter-to-modify-final-html-output) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand, You simply want to have all html from page. Why just don't do a request to the page in response You have html.

Here is the suggestion from codex:

```
/** @var array|WP_Error $response */
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html' );

if ( is_array( $response ) && ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $headers = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
    $body    = $response['body']; // use the content
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code is helpful but when should I execute that code? Ie, what action? Maybe on the `the_content' filter or maybe the `wp` action? Eg; `add_filter( 'the_content', $plugin_public, 'render_editor' );`

Comment: If You want to show response from request in content than the_content hook should works! :)